# Template for class versioning

Tags: c++, templates

I am not sure if this is strongly discouraged but I was thinking about using a template for versioning a class. In different versions I potentially have different methods and members. Later the "user" will specify the version at runtime.

```
template <uint8_t vID>
class Module;

template <>
class Module<3>
{
public:

  Module () : m_versionID(3) {};
  virtual ~ Module () = default;

  uint32_t versionID () const {return m_versionID;};
  uint32_t get3 () const {return 3;};
private:
  uint32_t m_versionID;
};


template <>
class Module <4>
{
public:

  Module () : m_versionID(4) {};
  virtual ~ Module () = default;

  uint32_t versionID () const {return m_versionID;};
  uint32_t get4 () const {return 4;};

private:
  uint32_t m_versionID;
};
```

This will work but I have the necessity of holding those modules in a larger class, as members

```
class Holder
{
public: 
  Holder(std::span<uint8_t> x) {m_mod = Module<x[0]>()} //something close to the real class
  const Module getModule() const {return m_mod;} 
  
private:
  Module m_mod;

}
```

Of course this will not work since when declaring `m_mod` I should specify the template argument (same in `getModule()`).

Any idea or recommendation for this kind of problem? Is this approach for class versioning usable?

Comment: What does having a class template give you over just having different classes? And you cannot just "remove" the template arguments to store it, you'll have to use a common base class/interface

Comment: Yeah I suspected that having a base module class was needed but I hoped there was something smarter

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is using something like [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), at least unless you're willing to go with dynamically allocated memory and a common base type. It doesn't really matter whether you're using different specializations of the same type or completely independent types. As for choosing the type given an integer: you could achieve the necessary case distinction using an ugly fold expression.

The following examle demonstrates the use of independent types. It also for simplicity replaces `std::span<uint8_t>` with `uint8_t` for simplicity:

```
class Module3
{
public:

    Module3() : m_versionID(3) {};
    virtual ~Module3() = default;

    uint32_t versionID() const { return m_versionID; };
    uint32_t get3() const { return 3; };
private:
    uint32_t m_versionID;
};

class Module4
{
public:

    Module4() : m_versionID(4) {};
    virtual ~Module4() = default;

    uint32_t versionID() const { return m_versionID; };
    uint32_t get4() const { return 4; };

private:
    uint32_t m_versionID;
};

template<class T>
struct ModuleIndex {};

template<>
struct ModuleIndex<Module3> : std::integral_constant<uint8_t, 3> {};
template<>
struct ModuleIndex<Module4> : std::integral_constant<uint8_t, 4> {};

class Holder
{
    using mod_type = std::variant<std::monostate, Module3, Module4>;

    template<size_t ... Is>
    Holder(uint8_t x, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        (((x == ModuleIndex<std::variant_alternative_t<Is + 1, mod_type>>::value) && (m_mod = std::variant_alternative_t<Is + 1, mod_type>{}, true)) || ...);
    }
public:
    Holder(uint8_t x)
        : Holder(x, std::make_index_sequence<std::variant_size_v<mod_type> -1>())
    {
    }

    template<class T>
    bool HoldsType() const
    {
        return std::holds_alternative<T>(m_mod);
    }

private:
    mod_type m_mod;

};

int main()
{
    Holder h3{ 3 };
    Holder h4{ 4 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << h3.HoldsType<Module3>() << '\n'
        << h4.HoldsType<Module4>() << '\n';
}
```

I don't see a type like this being useable though. Basically every operation on `Holder` would need to be implemented for `std::monostate`, `Module3` and `Module4`. You probably should use a similar constructor, but extend a common base class that provides a virtual destructor and pure virtual functions the module implementations implement and replace `std::variant` with `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>`...

```
class ModuleBase
{
public:
    virtual ~ModuleBase() = default;

    virtual uint32_t versionID() const = 0;
    virtual uint32_t get() const = 0;
};

class Module3 : public ModuleBase
{
public:

    Module3() : m_versionID(3) {};

    uint32_t versionID() const override { return m_versionID; };
    uint32_t get() const override { return 3; };
private:
    uint32_t m_versionID;
};

class Module4 : public ModuleBase
{
public:

    Module4() : m_versionID(4) {};
    virtual ~Module4() = default;

    uint32_t versionID() const override { return m_versionID; };
    uint32_t get() const override { return 4; };

private:
    uint32_t m_versionID;
};

template<class T>
struct ModuleIndex {};

template<>
struct ModuleIndex<Module3> : std::integral_constant<uint8_t, 3> {};
template<>
struct ModuleIndex<Module4> : std::integral_constant<uint8_t, 4> {};

class Holder
{
    template<class ... Ts>
    static std::unique_ptr<ModuleBase> make_mod(uint8_t x)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<ModuleBase> result;
        (((x == ModuleIndex<Ts>::value) && (result = std::make_unique<Ts>(), true)) || ...);
        return result;
    }
public:
    Holder(uint8_t x)
        : m_mod(make_mod<Module3, Module4>(x))
    {
    }

    const ModuleBase& getModule() const
    {
        assert(m_mod); // module shouldn't be empty
        return *m_mod;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<ModuleBase> m_mod;

};


int main()
{
    Holder h3{ 3 };
    Holder h4{ 4 };

    std::cout << h3.getModule().versionID() << '\n'
        << h4.getModule().versionID() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an abstract class Module with derived class implementations.  Your declaration of `m_mod` and the statement:

```
m_mod = Module<x[0]>();
```

cannot work because the the type `Module<...>` and the type of `m_mod` need to be determined at compile-time, but `x[0]` isn't provided until runtime.  What you're trying to do fundamentally cannot be done with templates.

If you had an abstract `Module` class and concrete implementations for your different versions, you could have a factory function like:

```
std::unique_ptr<Module> 
create_module( uint8_t version ) {
    switch( version ) {
       case 3:
           return std::make_unique<ModuleV3>();
       case 4:
           return std::make_unique<ModuleV4>();
       /// ...
    }
}
```

Your holder class would be:

```
class Holder {
public:
  Holder( std::span<uint8_t> x ) : m_mod{ create_module(x[0]) } {}
  const Module* getModule() const { return *m_mod; }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Module> m_mod;
};
```

I don't know how you would get "something smarter", since your problem matches the base class / derived class model exactly.

If you wanted to, you could make your derived classes template specializations as you've done before, but there's no getting around the runtime `switch` in the factory, so I don't think that would help.